# Trying to sum rows in an R tibble with a common value

Tags: r

I have the following tibble of data showing net profit for stocktrades on given days:

```
# A tibble: 114 x 3
   date       profit_loss net_profit
   <date>           <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2020-01-08           1       2105
 2 2020-01-15           1       2415
 3 2020-01-20           1        305
 4 2020-01-21           1       1120
 5 2020-01-23           1        235
 6 2020-01-23           1        235
 7 2020-01-30           1       -290
 8 2020-01-30           1      -2035
 9 2020-02-03           1       7640
10 2020-02-06           1      -2035
# ... with 104 more rows
```

As you can see there are several instances where there are more than one trade per day.  I would like to combine the rows that have the same date and sum the profit for those dates together to create a new dataframe that has all unique dates.

Is there a way to do this with group_by and summarise?  Or do I need to write some logical code that loops through the dataframe and compares the dates?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `result <- df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(net_profit = sum(net_profit))`

Comment: Thanks Ronak - that was just what I needed ;-)